# UIScrollView with UIImageView. Image is not scrolled up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Here's the code of the `UIScrollView`, `UIImageView`.
When the next image is chosen the `resetStatusImage` is called. `statusMessageImageView` is returned as a view for zooming in the UIScrollView delegate. 
When the minimal zoom is used, the image cannot be scrolled up, however there is still an image part to scroll. As for the bottom, left and right sides, they are fully visible and cannot be scrolled down, left and right respectively. Why the image cannot be scrolled up when zoomed minimally?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.statusMessageTextView.bounds.size.width, 455);
    statusMessageImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:r];
    statusMessageImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;

    // Set up the scroll view for the image zooming in/out and scrolling.
    imgScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:statusMessageImageView.bounds];
    [imgScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [imgScrollView setClipsToBounds:YES];

    [self.view addSubview:imgScrollView];

    [imgScrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

    [imgScrollView setContentSize:statusMessageImageView.frame.size]; // this is your image view size
    imgScrollView.delegate = self;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer =
        [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scrollViewDoubleTapped:)];
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [imgScrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

    [imgScrollView addSubview:statusMessageImageView];
    [imgScrollView addSubview:self.statusMessageTextView];
}
- (void)resetStatusImage
{
    imgScrollView.zoomScale = 1.0;

    UIImage *statusImage = self.statusImageManager.currentStatusImage;
    NSLog(@"Image size %f %f", statusImage.size.width, statusImage.size.height);

    // Set the image view fram size equal to the image size.
    statusMessageImageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=statusImage.size};
    [statusMessageImageView setImage:statusImage];

    // Set the scroll view content size and zoom scale.
    imgScrollView.contentSize = statusImage.size;
    CGFloat scaleWidth = imgScrollView.frame.size.width / imgScrollView.contentSize.width;
    CGFloat scaleHeight = imgScrollView.frame.size.height / imgScrollView.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat maxScale = MAX(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    imgScrollView.minimumZoomScale = maxScale;
    imgScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    imgScrollView.zoomScale = maxScale;

    // Save current scroll view content data
    // to detect that the user changed the visible area.
    contentOffsetX = imgScrollView.contentOffset.x;
    contentOffsetY = imgScrollView.contentOffset.y;
    zoomScale = imgScrollView.zoomScale;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`statusMessageTextView` height value was the mistake. Also disabled auto-scaling influences a position of the `statusMessageTextView` when scaling, moving the image: the text view is moved as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)inScroll {
 return imageView;
 }
```

This will help you.

Comment: But how does it help him? Can you add more information?